# Adding my application to the Finder's context menu?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, operating-system, finder

I have an application that I'm developing that deals with files of any type. I would like the user to be able to right click on *any type of file* in the Finder and have my menu option show up. I understand you have to add your application as a service to do this, however, whatever I put in the service settings in my Info.plist doesn't do the trick. I do register my application as a service with OS X, and I know it works because under service preferences my application's service shows up. However, I don't think I'm passing it the right type of parameters, because I can't activate my service by right-clicking on a file.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html)?

Also, this might be useful: [Writing a Snow Leopard Service for Finder.app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732142/writing-a-snow-leopard-service-for-finder-app)

Comment: Yes, I've looked all around the Apple docs. Stole stuff from other apps too. No luck.

Comment: What do you have on `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` and `handleServices:userData:error:`? And the relevant `plist` section?