# Establish a service in Finder context

Tags: swift, service, contextmenu, finder

I'm trying to add a service to the Finder's context menu using this class:

```
public class Service {
  public func handleServices(pboard:NSPasteboard, userData:String, error:UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<String>) {  // not sure about the correct parameters
    if (pboard.types?.contains(NSFilenamesPboardType) != nil) {
      let fileArray = pboard.propertyListForType(NSFilenamesPboardType)
      print(fileArray)
    }
  }

  init () {
    NSApp.servicesProvider = self
    NSUpdateDynamicServices()
  }
}
```

The service is announced in info.plist as follows:

```
<key>NSServices</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>NSMenuItem</key>
        <dict>
            <key>default</key>
            <string>Service Handling Demo</string>
        </dict>
        <key>NSMessage</key>
        <string>handleServices</string>
        <key>NSPortName</key>
        <string>services</string>
        <key>NSSendTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>NSFilenamesPboardType</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Finally I have turned on the service in System Preferences/Keyboard/Shortcuts. So I see the service and can call it. But all I get when calling it is

> Cannot find service provider for selector handleServices:userData:error: or handleServices:: for service handleServices

Comment: My *guess* would be that the class must inherit from `NSObject` (or marked with `@objc`).

Comment: @MartinR unfortunately no. I tried both and no change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

- *Objective-C messages* are sent to the service provider, therefore the Swift
  method must be "Objective-C compatible". This can be achieved by subclassing
  `NSObject`, or by marking the method with the `@objc` attribute.
- The service handler method has the signature

  ```
  - (void)handleServices:(NSPasteboard *)pboard
                userData:(NSString *)userData
                   error:(NSString **)error
  ```

  which is mapped to Swift as

  ```
  func handleServices(pboard: NSPasteboard!,
                    userData: String!,
                       error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>)
  ```

So this would be a correct version (which worked in my test):

```
public class Service {

    @objc public func handleServices(pboard: NSPasteboard!,
        userData: String!, error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>) {

        // ...
    }

    init() {
        NSApp.servicesProvider = self
        NSUpdateDynamicServices()
    }
}
```

Some more remarks:

```
if (pboard.types?.contains(NSFilenamesPboardType) != nil) { ... }
```

is "optional chaining" and checks if the `contains()` method could be called on `pboard.types`,
in other words it checks only if `pboard.types != nil`. What you probably want
is to check if `pboard.types != nil` *and* the `contains()` method returns `true`.
This can be achieved with the "nil-coalescing operator" `??`:

```
if (pboard.types?.contains(NSFilenamesPboardType) ?? false) { ... }
```

Next,

```
pboard.propertyListForType(NSFilenamesPboardType)
```

is documented to return an optional array of `NSString`s, so you could unwrap
and convert that to a `String` array with

```
if let fileArray = pboard.propertyListForType(NSFilenamesPboardType) as? [String] { ... }
```

Finally, assigning an error string (to the pointer provided by the
caller) would be done with

```
if (error != nil) {
    error.memory = "My error description"
}
```

Comment: I also made a small test and your code works indeed :-) Many thanks! There's another issue if I stuff it into my "real" app where I still get the "not found" message but I guess I'll find that by cutting down the code.

Answer (score 3):

Received same error (Swift 3.1). Tried all ways in this topic but nothing helped. Found a solution [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/73187)

Changed code from this

```
@objc public func handleServices(pboard: NSPasteboard!,
    userData: String!, error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>)
```

to this

```
@objc public func handleServices(_ pboard: NSPasteboard,
 userData: String, error:AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString>)
```

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating aliases for variables in your method like so.

```
public func handleServices(pboard:NSPasteboard, userData userData:String, error error:UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<String>)
```

Comment: Well, it will throw compiler warnings: "Extraneous duplicate parameter name; 'userData' already has an argument label"

Comment: @ThomasKilian Exactly. Although this syntax could work with Swift 2... (repeating the parameter name has replaced using `#` in front of it to make internal named parameters) but I don't see how it could help OP anyway. My comment was half snarky half real question (will this help OP or not? I think not, but if s1ddok could tell us why he thought this answer could help, I'd appreciate and, maybe, learn something).

Comment: @EricD. It looks like the #-syntax has been removed with Swift2.

Comment: @ThomasKilian That's exactly what I said. :) Also English is not my native language so maybe I wasn't clear with my explanation.